# Access Network Connection without using Control Panel

Tags: windows-xp, networking, control-panel

How do you access Network Connections without using the Control Panel?

I only know the following ways:

- Run `ncpa.cpl` from the command line.
- Right-click on your network icon in the System Tray, and select  `Open Network Connections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everything in Windows, there's about 5 ways to do it:

**My way**: Start, right-click on My Network Places, *P*roperties.

Others found in this thread and elsewhere:

- Desktop shortcuts to individual connections
- Sidebar navigation for My Network Places
- Right click the *S*tart button; Explore, select network
- **Winkey+E; left->down->right**

  - **Winkey+E; left->down->asterisk** (fully expands every share on the network -  `not recommended`)
- [this space intentionally left blank]

Comment: Nice!  Hadn't used the explorer shortcut before...